# Auto layout issue with fitting to screen sizes

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to make my scroll view (red background) to fit to the screen size with auto layout. I have set all of "spacing to nearest neighbour to 0 and have updated the frame. When I run it, the result was:
[image: this]

There are only two views in this controller. A scroll view embedded in a view. Am I missing other constraints?

Comment: have you checked the constraints of your view ?

Comment: @VinayRevankar the view is part of the viewController

Comment: @EricChuang Are you using XCode 6? I am also facing the same issue in iPad storyboard. Try to set left and right constraint -10 or -20

Comment: @zala YES,xcode 6, I fixed it by updating the superview of the red view.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the tick from "Constrain to margins":

[image: Constrain]